# Can an object other than a black hole have an event horizon?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

I haven't done the mathematics of it but is the radius of a potentially naturally occurring object such as a star held stable by quark degenerate matter or hypothesized preon degenerate matter small enough such that the object has an event horizon. I know you can just say if you had some object of this density and radius then it has an event horizon but, is it possible in nature?

Also what defines a black hole? Is it the fact it is an object with an escape velocity the speed of light or is it something that collapses to infinite density hence a star with an event horizon held together by some degenerate matter pressure?

No idea if any of this is correct. Apparently the laws of physics break down inside a black hole, so even though the pressure may be great enough just considering forces, it couldn't actually exist.

Comment: Well, basically a black hole is defined by having an event horizon, so everything that has an event horizon is called a black hole. So there are no things with an event horizon that aren't black holes.
As for degeneracy pressure, you might wanna look up [white dwarves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_dwarf) and [neutron stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star)

Comment: @Mladen Horizons are actually rather general. For example, you have cosmological horizons, Rindler horizons, etc.

Comment: @Dvij Agreed, but as far as I'm aware it should be safe to say that an object having an event horizon is always a black hole. (I don't consider the Universe an object here.)

Comment: @Mladen Seems like the case, but to be on the safer side, I would define a black hole as simply a singularity cloaked in at least one horizon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is small enough to have an event horizon it will crush to form a singularity, at least given GR. This is because once a horizon forms, everything inside is compelled to move into the center as all time-like paths, thus all those which all particles known to exist (and all which *can* exist assuming strict causality) are restricted to following, end up hitting the center. So the mass of neutron star MUST crush into the center, once inside a horizon radius.

But you can have horizons without black holes, just not an object shielded by one that is not a black hole. There is an event horizon far from Earth due to the expansion of the Universe.

Answer (score 1):

The black hole has an event horizon that is an invariant. The universe has a form of event horizon called the cosmological event horizon. However, this is not quite the same. It is an apparent horizon.

The Schwarzschild metric
$$
ds^2~=~\left(1~-~\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)dt^2~-~\left(1~-~\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)^{-1}dr^2~-~r^2d\Omega^2.
$$
The metric term $g_{tt}~=~\left(1~-~\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)$ $\rightarrow~0$ as $r~\rightarrow~\frac{2GM}{c^2}$. The blow up of $g_{rr}$ can be removed, so this is not a singularity. However, it is centered around the position of a gravitating mass at $r~=~0$. The spacetime solution is a vacuum solution around this singular point, which turns out to be a whole spatial surface instead of a point!

The de Sitter spacetime in stationary coordinates is
$$
ds^2~=~\left(1~-~r^2\Lambda/3\right)dt^2~-~\left(1~-~r^2\Lambda/3\right)^{-1}dr^2~-~r^2d\Omega^2.
$$
This is stationary because it is fixed at a coordinate origin $r~=~0$. which is not tied to a mass. There are more technical ways of working through this. but a transformation of coordinates moves the horizon as well. This means the horizon is different than the case with a black hole.

There is a case of something with an event horizon that is a bit odd. This is the Taub-NUT spacetime. This is similar to a black hole hole, but with metric term $1~-~\frac{\mu}{t}$, where $\mu$ is the NUT parameter that is analogous to the magnetic monopole; it is a gravitational form of a magnetic monopole. Here $t$ is of course time, and what this means is the event horizon occurs at some time in the past. It is proposed as a possible universe or cosmology. For $t~<~\mu$ the spacetime is nonchronal with closed timelike curves. This is a real event horizon and not a particle or apparent horizon that transforms with coordinate transformations.

Comment: Doesn't really help considering I have just finished A-level